# How can I confirm why a SQL Server query runs faster on development laptop than production server?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am finding that queries are taking slightly more than twice as long to complete on the production server compared to my development laptop.

My assumption (possibly incorrect) is that the query should be faster on the production server than on my little laptop.

I have done my best to make sure the set up and configurations are as equal as possible. The query is being run on the exact same data set etc.

The server is a VM, however the machine is not particularly busy and should have plenty of head room. The CPU/RAM usage rarely goes above 60%.

I have run `EXEC dbo.sp_BlitzFirst @Seconds = 30, @ExpertMode = 1;` and while I am not an expert on interpreting the results, I cannot see anything which might account for the difference:

[image]

One thing is that the VM has 4 processors available to SQL Server, whereas my laptop has 16. Could this account for the difference?

How can I confirm exactly what the bottleneck is?

**EDIT: Execution plan differences**

Thanks to the comments made by @TiborKaraszi and @J.D. I decided to create as simple a query as I could which would still take long enough to show a difference between my dev laptop and the server.

Doing this made it much easier to spot the differences between the plans.

The query I used was similar to below:

```
  declare @i int, @c int
    select @i = 1, @c = 100;--Change @c to suit
    with X as (
        select @i as N union all select N + 1 from x where N < @c
    )
    select 
        T.*
    from
        X,
    (   
        select TOP (200)
            *
        from
            dbo.MyTableName --Change to one of your tables 
    ) AS T
    option (MaxRecursion 0)
```

The resulting execution plans were almost identical. I believe the main difference is the following line:

Laptop (took 1 second):

```
<QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" CachedPlanSize="56" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="312">
```

Server (took 14 seconds):

```
<QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="56" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="312">
```

Assuming that this difference in the plans could cause the difference in execution time...

What could be the actual cause of the different plans?

Does it point to a setting which is different on the server?

Comment: Start with the actual execution plan. If it goes parallel, then yes, more CPUs can definitely be the reason. If there are different plans alltogether between the two, well then you have your answer there as well.

Comment: Looking at the plans, they do not seem to go parallel. There are some differences between the two plans, but I don't know how to analyse them well enough to know what they are telling me or how to improve the slower one. Do you have any suggestions or links to resources which might be helpful?

Comment: I guess that would be any article about reading and understanding execution plans. I don't have a set of such at hand. Google is your friend, and other readers are also welcome to add their favourites. You can of course share the DDL, sample data, actual plan etc (in a new post?) here to get feedback on your particular situation.

Comment: How long are the queries taking?  Those waits show 400ms of ASYNC_NETWORK_IO, which is sending results to the client.  That will obviously be slower when connecting to a remote server than on your local laptop.

Comment: As suggested by Tibor, you can add the execution plans to your question by uploading them to [Paste The Plan](https://www.BrentOzar.com/PasteThePlan) and adding the link to your post. Someone here should be able to explain the differences, the cause of those differences, and their impact on your query's performance.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It depends on the exact query but as an example, one on my laptop is taking 12 seconds, whereas on the server it is taking 37 seconds. So I think we can rule out the network as a cause.

Comment: Management Studio has a built-in tool for comparing plans. I'd suggest using that. It's going to be much more accurate than looking at them line-by-line: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/compare-execution-plans

Comment: The difference you have shown there, says that plans can't go parallel on your server, and they can on your laptop. That implies that there are differences in SQL Server settings. You might want to explore those as well as the differences in plans.

Comment: @GrantFritchey Thanks. I will have a look at that tool. But in this case, I don't think it will make a difference. I used an online tool that highlights differences, and there were very few. Can you suggest what server settings in particular? MAXDOP and threshold are 0 and 5 respectively on both machines. When I forced the server to run the query in parallel (with `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8649)`) it made no difference to execution time.

Comment: Test with MAXDOP 1 and MAXDOP 4 to see if parallelism accounts for the difference.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I tried that but it made no difference to the query plan (or execution time)

Comment: Then try with STATISTICS TIME and STATISTICS IO on and post the output and actual execution plans.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am sorry. I don't know what "with STATISTICS TIME and STATISTICS IO on" means.  But thank you - it gives me something else to research. Really what I was hoping for from this question was someone to post an answer detailing the exact steps that should be taken (rather than just explaining what is happening in this one specific case). I am sort of getting there through the helpful comments and research, but nothing I have done so far has highlighted (to me at least) any key differences, nor anything which might delay the query.

Comment: Did you compare the actual execution plans?

Comment: MAXDOP, cost threshold, general cpu settings & affinity, stuff like that. However, all of them really. ANSI connection defaults can affect plan generation and behavior. Also, don't forget about relative age of the machines. we had a dev server once that was radically faster than production. After tons of testing, we realized it was just a newer chip set.